# Identity server CORS error while calling API from Angular client

Tags: angular, api, cors, identityserver4

Hi I created an Angular app which is connected to the Identity Server 4 for authentication. I registered the angular client with AllowedCorsOrigins, and Scopes are accessing API. I also have other clients ".net core MVC" which also have the same scope (accessing API).I dont have any issue with MVC client but angular I am getting CORS error.

**Identity Server Client**

```
new Client
        {
            ClientId = "clientangularSLO",
            ClientName = "Angular Client",
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
            RequireClientSecret = false,
            AllowedScopes = new List<string>
            {
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                "api1",
                "roles"
            },

            
            RedirectUris = new List<string> {"http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:4300"},
            PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string> {"http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:4300"},
            AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string> { "http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:4300" },

            AccessTokenLifetime = 120,  //2mins 
            RequireConsent= true,
            RequirePkce = true,
            AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
            AllowOfflineAccess = true,
            
        }
```

**API Scope**

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
        new List<ApiScope>
        {
            new ApiScope("api1", "Test API",new List<string>() { "role" })            
        };
```

**Angular Client**
I am using angular-auth-oidc-client 11.5.1

```
    export function configureAuth(oidcConfigService: OidcConfigService) {
  return () =>
    oidcConfigService.withConfig({
      stsServer: 'https://localhost:5001',
      redirectUrl: window.location.origin,
      clientId: 'clientangularSLO',
      scope: 'openid profile api1',
      responseType: 'code',
      triggerAuthorizationResultEvent: true,
      postLogoutRedirectUri: `${window.location.origin}/unauthorized`,
      
      logLevel: LogLevel.Debug,
      historyCleanupOff: true,
                 
    });
```

I tried to add Cors in API, I am not sure this is the correct wasy

**API --> StartUp.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //services.AddCors(c =>
            //{
            //    c.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", options => 
            //        options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:4300")
            //        .AllowAnyMethod()
            //        .AllowAnyHeader()                 
            //    );
            //});

           
            services.AddSingleton<ICorsPolicyService>((container) => {
                var logger = container.GetRequiredService<ILogger<DefaultCorsPolicyService>>();
                return new DefaultCorsPolicyService(logger)
                {
                    //AllowedOrigins = { "http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:4300" }
                    AllowAll = true
                };
            });
            
            services.AddAuthorization(opt =>
            {
                opt.AddPolicy("Apiscope", policy =>
                {
                    policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                    policy.RequireClaim("Scope", "api1");
                    
                });

            });
}


 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin());
            //app.UseCors(options => options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:4300"));

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();
        
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers()
                    .RequireAuthorization("ApiScope"); //checking the policy "Apiscope"
            });
        }
```

**HttpInterceptor to add token**

```
 private getToken(){
    return this.oidcSecurityService.getToken();
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    
    if(this.tokenValue){
      request = request.clone( {
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization : `Bearer ${this.getToken()}`
        }
      })
    }

    return next.handle(request);
  }
```

I am using Angular11 and Identity server v4.0.0 . Please advice me , the correct way to solve this issue.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your comments.

This is resolved by adding **AllowAnyHeader()** and **AllowAnyMethod()** in API config

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseCors(options =>
            options.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            );

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();
    
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers()
                .RequireAuthorization("ApiScope"); //checking the policy "Apiscope"
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure that I fully understood the context, but I suspect, that the .NET Core backend service, which serves the Angular app does not use the proxy configuration to the Angular development server on port 4200.

Therefore in the `Startup.cs` of the .NET based Angular backend service in `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` following configuration is needed:

```
services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
{
    configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
});
```

and in `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)`

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
    // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501
     spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
    }
 });
```

See details here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

I recommend to generate a project with `dotnet new angular -o my-new-app` and check the configurations there.
This approach is commonly used to avoid cross-origin calls if we want to run the Angular development server with `ng serve` independently.

If this approach already works the next step is to configure the identity server correctly.

Answer (score -1):

try add this 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' to your request